# Appending my var if the user has not been already added

Tags: jquery, append

I want to check before appending the user in my div if this user doesn't exist in my div.

```
// Adding the user if he has not been already added in my div
$(".ajax_panel_append").fadeIn(3000);
$(".ajax_panel_append").append("<a href='#' alt='" + user_id + "|" + user_name + "' class='chat_user'>" + user_name + "</a>");
```

How can i do it please ?

Answer (score 0):

You're adding now your users, one thing you can do is to have your users as javascript objects something like this:

```
var user ={
    id: 10,
    name: "user1"
}

var user2 ={
    id: 10,
    name: "user2"
}
```

And then just define a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function where we can check for the current `a` elements inside our div.

```
    var elem = $(".ajax_panel_append a").filter(function() { 
            //Also you can define here another condition filter will return the elements
            //that met your condition in this case if the element has the same text or 
           //the alt attr
            return $(this).attr("alt") == user.id+"|"+user.name;
   });
```

The proposed function will be something like this

```
function addUser(user){
    //Search for User elem will hold all the elements that match the condition
    var elem = $(".ajax_panel_append a").filter(function() { 
            return $(this).attr("alt") == user.id+"|"+user.name;
    });

   //If elem is different from 0 this means that we have elements that match the 
   //combination of userid and name so we can't add them again.
   if(elem.length == 0){
      //Add the new element
      $(".ajax_panel_append").append("<a href='#' alt='" + user.id + "|" + user.name + "'    class='chat_user'>" + user.name + "</a>"); 
    }

}
```

[**Fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/268SS/)